Where can I find a guide on installing Mac OS on windows 10 computer using Virtual Box 7.1.4?
I tried following User Donald Duck's well detailed guide to load macOS into Virtual Box.
that I followed (URL at end) for what must have been an earlier version of Vbox. I'm hoping there is a current Guide using any version of VBOX that will run in Windows 10.
I even checked the original date of Donald Duck's Guide posting and installed vbox v 5.0.36; the version current at the time in May 2017. That version installs but won't run on Windows 10.
Below is the URL to the guide.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739387/build-an-ios-app-without-owning-a-mac
Thank you for any help.....
